# How to create a shortcut to a VMWare Workstation Player 15 VM?

Tags: windows, vmware, vmware-player

I'd like to start a VMWare Workstation Player specific Virtual Machine from a link, rather than starting VMWare, then double-clicking on the VM.

VMWare provides an [explanation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2097688) on this procedure for the Pro product, but it doesn't work with the Player.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr: Required command `vmplayer.exe HelloWorld.vmx`

First find the `vmplayer.exe` executable full path. Default path is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmplayer.exe"
```

Run that path with `--help` option in Command Prompt for the help window:

> Usage: vmplayer.exe [OPTION ...] [--] [configuration file]
>
> where OPTIONS are:
>
> ```
> -v          Show program version
> -X          Enter full screen mode
>             when a virtual machine is powered on
> --unity     Enter Unity
>             when a virtual machine is powered on
> ```

[image: vmware_player_help_window]

Now find the required VMware virtual machine configuration file with .VMX
file extension. For example:

```
"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Virtual Machines\Windows 10 x64\Windows 10 x64.vmx"
```

Hence the full command will be like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmplayer.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Virtual Machines\Windows 10 x64\Windows 10 x64.vmx"
```

Too long, isn't it? Create a shortcut of `vmplayer.exe` with that command. This also works in Command Prompt. Make sure to user double quote the path because the path 
contains spaces. [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=vmplayer+command+options) may help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just double-click on the VM's `.vmx` file.  If you have only VMware (Workstation) Player installed (and not VMware Workstation Pro), then the VM should automatically open in Player.

If you want to double-click on an icon from a more convenient location, you can do a right-mouse-button drag on the `.vmx` file to create a shortcut to it and then move the shortcut wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

VMware KVM mode shortcut is a better way!

Create desktop shortcut with this target:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-kvm.exe" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 10 x64\Windows 10 x64.vmx"

Read this article for more information:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2057914